# How to compare two images in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, image, comparison

How to compare images from my local directory with the downloaded image. Comparison showld be based on image content and size.

How to do this in ruby?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this.

1) For my opinion the best way is using Rmagick signature(thanks to [this useful manual](http://blog.daniellobato.me/2012/06/comparing-images-in-rub/)):

```
require 'RMagick'

new_image = Magick::Image.read(new_photo)[0]        ## new_photo = "/your/dir/file.jpg"
expected_image = Magick::Image.read(expected_photo)[0]

new_image.signature.should eql expected_image.signature
```

or

```
diff_img, diff_metric  = img1[0].compare_channel( img2[0], Magick::MeanSquaredErrorMetric )
```

2) You also can use raster_graphics library ([rosettacode.org](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Percentage_difference_between_images)):

```
require 'raster_graphics'

class RGBColour

 # the difference between two colours
 def -(a_colour)
   (@red - a_colour.red).abs +
   (@green - a_colour.green).abs +
   (@blue - a_colour.blue).abs
 end
end

class Pixmap

# the difference between two images
  def -(a_pixmap)
    if @width != a_pixmap.width or @height != a_pixmap.height
      raise ArgumentError, "can't compare images with different sizes"
    end
    sum = 0
    each_pixel {|x,y| sum += self[x,y] - a_pixmap[x,y]}
    Float(sum) / (@width * @height * 255 * 3)
  end
end

lenna50 = Pixmap.open_from_jpeg('Lenna50.jpg')
lenna100 = Pixmap.open_from_jpeg('Lenna100.jpg')

puts "difference: %.5f%%" % (100.0 * (lenna50 - lenna100))

#=>:
#difference: 1.62559%
```